# Options for embedding fonts in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fonts

Is there a way that I can convert a font file to a buffer or svgs or something and embed it within a js bundle?

The way the app will be used means I can't link to a hosted font file and I won't have access to the local file system.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: React itself will not solve it, use a webpack for it. It can encode fonts into base64 inside styles. But I still do not understand why you can not download it regularly.

Answer (score 0):

You can include ttf (font files) into your project and then modify your config.js to bundle it together:

```
let rules = []  
  rules.push({
      test: /\.ttf$/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]'}
    })

    module.exports = () => {
      module: { rules },
      ...
    }
```